# Absolute percentage position working on desktop, in Chrome dev tools, but not on mobile

Tags: css, iphone, reactjs, mobile, responsive-design

I just deployed my first React website, and everything looks the way it should in  desktop Chrome and Safari, but it's off in Safari on my iPhone 7. The biggest issue is that the text container (child) div is showing up too high in the parent div. The text container div is inline styled:

```
position: "absolute",
bottom: "10%",
transform: "translateY(-50%)",
```

The parent div is styled as `position: relative`. However, the child div is roughly vertically centered in the containing div, when it should be hugging near the bottom of the parent div. How can I fix this?

The site is jamiew.io

Comment: I'd try using Safari's Responsive Design Mode to emulate different device screens?

Comment: On a smaller screen, the percentage from the bottom (which is being affected by both the `bottom` value and the `transform` value) is simply visually higher. Consider using media queries to change one of those values on small screens (or just take off the transform on mobile).

Comment: Thanks ingridly. I ended up removing transform altogether. How can I give you credit/karma for answering?